# I have created a employee id tabview list i have to change it to dictionary

Tags: mvvm, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swyve.png)

i have used list with mvvm but my seniors told me use

```
dict<string, Employee> =
{
  {"Employee 1" ,{id, emailid , name , father name , employee id , adddress}}
  {"Employee 2" ,{id, emailid , name , father name , employee id , adddress}}
  {"Employee 3" ,{id, emailid , name , father name , employee id , adddress}}
  {"Employee 4" ,{id, emailid , name , father name , employee id , adddress}}
  {"Employee 5" ,{id, emailid , name , father name , employee id , adddress}}
}
```

i am not able to change it to dictionary can anyone do it or give me some reference

Comment: Dictionary is fast for lookup than list. Create a dictionary  IDictionary<string, Employee> openWith = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();
then add a item.

sample reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=net-7.0#examples

Comment: getting this error - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error (active) CS0030 Cannot convert type 'File_Upload.ViewModels.EmployeeIDViewModel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, EmployeeIDViewModel>'

Comment: someone please create this'

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are key-value collections. For every item, you have to specify a unique id.
For example:

```
var EmployeesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();
EmployeesDictionary["empId"] = new Employee();
```

In your case you could populate your collection like that:

```
private record Employee(
   int Id,
   string EmpTab,
   string EmailId,
   string Name,
   string FatherName,
   string EmpId,
   string Address);

private void LoadEmployees()
{
   var EmployeesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Employee>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      EmployeesDictionary.Add(i, new Employee(
         Id: i,
         EmpTab: "EmptTab",
         EmailId: "Email",
         Name: "Name",
         FatherName: "FatherName",
         EmpId: "EmpId",
         Address: "Address"));
   }
}
```

You also could convert your list using LINQ:

```
private record Employee(
   int Id,
   string EmpTab,
   string EmailId,
   string Name,
   string FatherName,
   string EmpId,
   string Address);

private void LoadEmplEmployees()
{
   var EmployeesDictionary = new List<Employee>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      EmployeesDictionary.Add(new Employee(
         Id: i,
         EmpTab: "EmptTab",
         EmailId: "Email",
         Name: "Name",
         FatherName: "FatherName",
         EmpId: "EmpId",
         Address: "Address"));
   }

   EmployeesDictionary.ToDictionary(e => e.Id, e => e);

}
```

[Dictionary Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0)
[LINQ ToDictionary Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__)

Comment: @foreach (var data in LoadEmployees)
  {

        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Emailid</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Father name</th>
        <th scope="col">Employee id</th>
        <th scope="col">Address</th>

       </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       <tr style="font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">

        <td>@ID</td>
        <td>@EmailID</td>
        <td>@Name</td>
        <td>@FatherName</td>
        <td>@EmpID</td>
        <td>@Address</td>
       </tr>

Comment: how can i bind in the page when the data come from this dictionary